# Exiting a do-loop with sentinel value before the else clause kick in

Tags: java, do-loops

I'm writing a piece of code for my assignment from school. I already finished and got it working fine but one thing is bugging me. How do I make the do-loop exit without printing the line That is NOT a Palindrome. I just know it's gonna be a simple solution but can't seem to figure it out. I had some other methods underneath the main class but it doesn't matter in this context so I didn't include it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userPhrase;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            userPhrase = "";
            System.out.print("Enter phrase (done to stop): ");
            userPhrase = in.nextLine();
            userPhrase = userPhrase.toLowerCase();
            userPhrase = delSpecialChar(userPhrase);
            if (palChecker(userPhrase)) {
                System.out.println("That is a Palindrome\n");
            } else {System.out.println("That is NOT a Palindrome\n");}
        } while (!userPhrase.equals("done"));
        in.close();
    }
```

Here's what it looks like when I entered done:

```
Enter phrase (done to stop): done
That is NOT a Palindrome
```

*Program terminated*

Comment: to exit loop just use `break;`

Comment: it would exit if I typed done in but I don't want the line That is NOT a Palindrome to show up

Comment: so would i just add this it like this 
``if (userPhrase.equals("done")) {break;}
else if (palChecker(userPhrase)) {
System.out.println("That is a Palindrome\n");
   } else {System.out.println("That is NOT a Palindrome\n");}``

Comment: okay, i figured it out. thank you! im still in school so simple things like this can fly over my head

Comment: i've always wondered why have a condition in a loop when you can use if-break. it seemed counter intuitive it makes sense now that you explained it like that